# build tensorflow with HEXAGON_LIBS

Tags: tensorflow, hexagon-dsp

I want to build tensorflow with qualcomm hexagon libraries, just as the makefile like this

`tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile`

```
ifdef HEXAGON_LIBS

    LIBGEMM_WRAPPER := $(HEXAGON_LIBS)/libgemm_wrapper.so

    ifeq ($(shell test -f $(LIBGEMM_WRAPPER) 2> /dev/null; echo $$?), 0)

$(info "Use hexagon libs at " $(LIBGEMM_WRAPPER))

    else

$(error "hexagon libs not found at " $(LIBGEMM_WRAPPER))

    endif
```

but I cannot find the `libgemm_wrapper.so` in the HEXAGON SDK of Qualcomm.

Answer (score 4):

The Hexagon support is still a work in progress, which is why we haven't announced it widely, so unfortunately that library is not yet ready. We hope to have it available soon.

Comment: any update? would love any resources explaining the new DSP integration capabilities - also any approximate benchmarks for speedup over a well tuned vectorized SIMD matmul implementation would be literally gold. Thanks!!

Comment: @Pete, could you update on this project? I am seeing many recent commits on github.